# How can i catch any error caused by unset module variable?

Tags: python-3.x

So I have this function list and showlist but i need to catch any error caused by an unset module variable. can someone help me whats the first thing i should do?

this is my code at the moment

```
import csv

filep  #filepath
menulist = []

def list():
    """Function to read the csv file, create a nested list 
    and return the list that is sorted based on calories 
    in the ascending order."""

    global menulist
    menulist = [] #store items
    with open(filep) as csv_file: #read file
        reader = csv.reader (csv_file, delimiter=',')
        next(reader, None)

        for row in reader:
            row[2] = int(row[2].strip())
            row[1] = float(row[1].strip())
            if row[2]> 100 and row[2] <200:
                menulist.append(row)

    menulist.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])


def show_list():#Function to display menu
    global menulist
    for i in range(len(menulist)):
        print ('%-4d%-20s%-15s%-15s' %(i + 1, menulist[i][0], menulist[i][2], menulist[i][1]))

list()
show_list()
```

for example, if the variable file is not set before the list() is called, the function needs to catch an error and prints an appropriate comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a built-in function name as your function name. Which is not considered as a good practice in Python. It replaces the built-in function `list()` which is used to create a list. And you need to define a variable before you can use it.

Here's how you can catch the error and print an appropriate comment, with the variable defined:

```py
import csv

filep = str(input("Enter the file name with path : "))  # filepath
menulist = []


def calorieList():
    """Function to read the csv file, create a nested list
    and return the list that is sorted based on calories
    in the ascending order."""

    global menulist
    menulist = []  # store items
    with open(filep) as csv_file:  # read file
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
        next(reader, None)

        for row in reader:
            row[2] = int(row[2].strip())
            row[1] = float(row[1].strip())
            if row[2] > 100 and row[2] < 200:
                menulist.append(row)

    menulist.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])


def show_list():  # Function to display menu
    global menulist
    for i in range(len(menulist)):
        print("%-4d%-20s%-15s%-15s" % (i + 1, menulist[i][0], menulist[i][2], menulist[i][1]))


try:
    calorieList()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Enter a valid file path.")

show_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant `filep` by the `file` variable.
If you try to access `filep` before it is set, your program should raise `NameError: name 'filep' is not defined`.

But if you want to raise a custom error message, you can just use a try-except block as follows:

```
import csv

filep  #filepath
menulist = []
def list():
    """Function to read the csv file, create a nested list
    and return the list that is sorted based on calories
    in the ascending order."""

    global menulist
    menulist = [] #store items
    try:
        with open(filep) as csv_file: #read file
            reader = csv.reader (csv_file, delimiter=',')
            next(reader, None)

            for row in reader:
                row[2] = int(row[2].strip())
                row[1] = float(row[1].strip())
                if row[2]> 100 and row[2] <200:
                    menulist.append(row)
    except NameError:
        raise ValueError("Your custom message here")

    menulist.sort(key=lambda x: x[-1])


def show_list():#Function to display menu
    global menulist
    for i in range(len(menulist)):
        print ('%-4d%-20s%-15s%-15s' %(i + 1, menulist[i][0], menulist[i][2], menulist[i][]))

list()
show_list()
```